# Duplicate entry error but dupes are there

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

**+++UPDATE+++

I just discovered is that there is the same insert statement in another script. That's why causes this error.

+++UPDATE+++**

I am getting an error when inserting into a temp table that's created thusly

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stage_package_dim (
`account_key` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
`processdate_est_key` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`package_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`package_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`package_description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`package_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`package_order` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '1',
`package_cost` DECIMAL(16,4) NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`package_credits` DECIMAL(16,4) NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
PRIMARY KEY (`account_key`, `processdate_est_key`, `package_id`),
INDEX `package_type` (`package_type`)
```

);

The error reads

```
Duplicate entry '1000000000000000001-1368576000-6001' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So I tried to find the dupes for my composite key but I don't think my query is correct

```
SELECT
 account_key,COUNT(distinct processdate_est_key,package_id)
 FROM  staging_package_dim
GROUP BY account_key
HAVING COUNT(account_key) >1 order by 1 limit 10
```

but it's giving me the following result

```
+---------------------+--------------------+
| account_key | COUNT(account_key) |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| 1000000000000001001 | 1473 |
| 1000000000000002001 | 623 |
| 1000000000000003001 | 745 |
```

The composite key should not allow dupes, correct? How do I get the unique values for my primary key? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results that you want.

Comment: Having a composite primary key means that you are not allowed to insert 2 rows each one having `account_key = 1000000000000000001`, `processdate_est_key = 1368576000 and package_id = 6001 `

Comment: Your diagnostic approach is strange. What does `SELECT * FROM staging_package_dim WHERE account_key = '1000000000000000001' AND processdate_est_key = '1368576000' AND package_id = '6001'` return? Surely, one row at most.

Comment: There are no duplicates in the table. They are forbidden. So with a correct query (see my answer on this) you could not find any duplicates. There either is a record with account_key = '1000000000000000001, processdate_est_key = 1368576000, and package_id = 6001 already in the table or your insert statement tries to insert two such records.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I see my mistake now. Then what causes this error message? This is completely misleading - I rebuild the temp table at runtime so this record isn't already in the table and there is only one occurrence of this account key.

Comment: The error is created by the second insertion attempt with such values. As it is an error (rather than warning) the insertion does not complete. Depending on how you populate the temp table both insertions can even live on the same query.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The same insert statement in another script. That's why causes this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query to demonstrate that there are no duplicates in the table is:

```
select account_key, processdate_est_key, package_id
from staging_package_dim
group by account_key, processdate_est_key, package_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

This will return no rows, because `account_key` + `processdate_est_key` + `package_id` are the table's primary key.

Your query is wrong, because `account_key` alone is not the table's primary key. It is allowed to have multiple records for the same `account_key` in the table.

Comment: I see that now. You make complete sense. But it's a temp table that I create every time `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...` so there can be no duplicates there already when I make my `INSERT` statement.

Comment: If the table is empty, but you are getting this error, then this is because you are trying to insert the same key twice. Let's say first_name + last_name were the unique key and you'd write `insert into mytable (first_name, last_name) select forename, surname from users`; there may be two John Smith in the users table and you'd get the error.

Comment: I just discovered is that there is the **same** insert statement in another script. That's why causes this error.